# DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() modify user agent

Tags: php, domdocument, user-agent

Im using PHP to load a website in a DOM Tree. Is there a way to modify the user agent that is sent using `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`?

```
function parseThis($url)
{
  $html = new DOMDocument();
  $html->loadHtmlFile( $url );

  return $html
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the `user_agent` value in `php.ini`, which should be sent in anything making use of the http stream wrapper like `DOMDocument::loadHtmlFile(), file_get_contents()`, etc.

```
$fake_user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11";
ini_set('user_agent', $fake_user_agent);
```

The same can also be accomplished in an Apache `.htaccess` by setting `php_value user_agent` if permitted by your server configuration.

Comment: Oh interesting, didn't knew this possibility

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think the best way to do is to retrieve the content in a different way and load the document after. You can do that using cURL.

```
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

$ch = curl_init();

// set user agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab content from the website
$content = curl_exec($ch);

// load the content in your dom
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($content);
```