# RSS and php parsing error

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am hopeing somebody can help me out with an RSS feed issue I am having, working locally, using XAMPP.

I am trying to display two RSS feeds on my website. One from *BBC Education* which works, and one from a *Joomla* site, which doesn't work.

The php code I am using is **identical** in both cases apart from the *url*, perhaps I have to change my php some way for each feed? The feeds are on the same page, although this shouldn't matter?

The (working) BBC feed is [here](http://view-source:http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/education/rss.xml?edition=uk)

The php code I use to successfully display this feed is below;

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/education/rss.xml?edition=uk');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
     'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
     'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
     'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
     );
    array_push($feed, $item);
    } 
    $limit = 3;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }  
    ?>
    </br>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

The (not working) Joomla feed is [here](http://www.littlehandssurestart.co.uk/blog?format=feed&type=rss)

The code I use to (unsuccessfully) display this feed is below;

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://www.littlehandssurestart.co.uk/blog?format=feed&type=rss');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
     'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
     'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
     'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
     );
    array_push($feed, $item);
    } 
    $limit = 3;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }  
    ?>
    </br>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

The error is receive regarding the Joomla feed above is as follows;

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Empty string supplied as input in C:\xampp\htdocs\logintest\application\views\index\index.php on line 124

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\logintest\application\views\index\index.php on line 136

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\logintest\application\views\index\index.php on line 137

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\logintest\application\views\index\index.php on line 138
```

I have read that this can be due to unclosed `/>` tags? However I can't find any. Quite new to php so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Solution: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php#91384

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily apparently, the `load()` function of `DOMDocument` doesn't send a `User-Agent` header. That fact causing a 500 error and a warning is being raised (this depends on webserver configuration, not all webservers throw a 500 error in case the User-Agent is not set).

There are two ways to add a user-agent in this case. The first one is based on the used standard [HTTP stream context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) and the second one on [the more specific libxml ones](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php).

The first method is to change the default ini-setting in PHP for the user-agent string:

```
$fake_user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11";
ini_set('user_agent', $fake_user_agent);
```

This has been taking over from a  [previous answer to the question *"DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() modify user agent"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11496070/367456).

A second method is based on [JonasDue Vesterheden's comment](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php#91384) on the php manual.

The offered solution is to create a stream with the mentioned headers, which can be achieved by the following:

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHP libxml agent',
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);
```

This has also been outlined in a [previous answer to the question *"DOMDocument::validate() problem"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4063009/367456).